# FFT in different coordinate systems

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

Is there a transformation that will enable one to calculate the FFT in an arbitrary coordinate system? What I am interested is the following two cases:

1. The space is Euclidean and infinitely differentiable everywhere
2. The space forms a curved Riemannian manifold with metric:
   $$ds^2 = \sum_{i, j} g_{ij} dx^i dx^j$$

Comment: Hi there! Interesting question! Please give more details and clarify: the **coordinate system** you refer is a **spatial** construct to measure space coordinates of points? That can makes sense for image analsysis in non cartesian or non curvilinear coordinate systems...

Comment: Well, the coordinate system does not matter from a mathematical point of view. Usually we have samples on a grid i.e. Rectangular coordinates. What if the samples are in some arbitrary coordinate system of dimension N.

Comment: ok then please make that arbitrary coordinate system more specific; i.e. a warped space? nonorthogonal? or just nonuniform samples from a rectengular or polar grid? In case of nonuniform samples, it can (possibly) be converted to uniform ones and usual DFT can be obtained then.

Comment: A manifold? Hmm lets see who has taken a differential geometry course here :)

Comment: Well case 1 is eucledian but the samples are not uniform in some manner. So if it is in polar coordinates you will get more samples near the origin. What if the coordinate system is not polar but an arbitrary one?

Comment: Well, your problem seems more mathematical than signal processing. Cause I cannot much see an immediate practical application of a Riemannian space being sampled nonuniformly (GPS satellites? BlackHole simulation? General Relativity? Space waves recently detected ?)

Comment: The Riemannian space is actually an after thought trying to generalize the result. Say you have a flight path around an object that is not circular and you want to do tomography using the projection slice theorem. For that you need to do the 2d FFT to get your slices and then do the 3D ifft to get the 3 dimensional object. Usually we interpolate the data back to Cartesian coordinates and do the ifft. But I was thinking, can't you calculate the ifft while the data is not in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Ok you can rephrase your question into "Doing FFT in nonuniformly sampled data for computational tomography problem" which can get much relevant responses. In my experince I have worked with nonuiform sampling and there are methods to convert nonuniform samples back to uniform ones after which you can safely use uniform FFTs.